# Javascript - basic programing, can´t change picture

Tags: javascript, html

I have five jpg pictures and on a homepage i want to choose between these five pics by typing 1,2,3,4 or 5 and click OK and then i want that picture to show.

**My code looks like this:**

```
var inputElem, msgElem;

function init() {
msgElem = document.getElementById("message");
    inputElem = [];
    inputElem[1] = document.getElementById("input1");
    inputElem[2] = document.getElementById("input2");
    inputElem[3] = document.getElementById("input3");
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = showFruit;

}

 window.onload = init; 

function showFruit() {
var nr, fruitUrl;

fruitUrl = (fruitImg.src = "pics/fruit" + nr + ".jpg");
nr = Number(input1.value);

fruitImg.src = "pics/fruit" + nr + ".jpg";

fruitUrl = document.getElementById("fruitImg").src = "pics/fruit1.jpg";
```

The problem is that I can't change the picture.I don't know whats missing, or how to make it choose between pic 1-5.

Answer (score 1):

I have no privilege to write comments, so can't estimate what you actually want. But the resulting effect may be the thing you want.

But have look up below examples ([live here](http://dilaraism.me.pn/test/36529547/index.html)). Enter a number then click button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="image">
    <img src="salon1.jpg" id="fruit">
</div>
        <input type="number" id="inp">
        <input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="showFruit('inp')">

<script type="text/javascript">

    makeImageFromNum = function (n) {
        var nr = document.getElementById(n).value;
        if (parseInt(nr)>5) {
            nr = 5;
        }
        else if (parseInt(nr)<1) {
            nr = 1;
        }
        return "salon"+nr+".jpg";
    }

    showFruit = function (n) {
        document.getElementById("fruit").src = makeImageFromNum(n);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In below example ([live here](http://dilaraism.me.pn/test/36529547/index_2.html)) just change the number - no need to click a button, there is no any actually :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="image">
    <img src="salon1.jpg" id="fruit">
</div>
        <input type="number" id="inp" onchange="showFruit(this.value)">

<script type="text/javascript">

    makeImageFromNum = function (nr) {
        if (parseInt(nr)>5) {
            nr = 5;
        }
        else if (parseInt(nr)<1) {
            nr = 1;
        }
        return "salon"+nr+".jpg";
    }

    showFruit = function (n) {
        document.getElementById("fruit").src = makeImageFromNum(n);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're always assinging the first image in this line of code (the last Iine if your code)

```
fruitUrl = document.getElementById("fruitImg").src = "pics/fruit1.jpg";
```

So, you'll always see image one